# lxml find tags by regex

Tags: python, xml, tags, lxml

I'm trying to use lxml to get an array of tags that are formatted as

```
<TEXT1>TEXT</TEXT1>

<TEXT2>TEXT</TEXT2>

<TEXT3>TEXT</TEXT3>
```

I tried using

```
xml_file.findall("TEXT*")
```

but this searches for a literal asterisk.

I've also try to use **ETXPath** but it seems to not work.
Is there any API function to work with that, because assuming that
*TEXT* is append by integers isn't the prettiest solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use [regular expressions in lxml xpath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#regular-expressions-in-xpath).

Here is one example:

```
results = root.xpath(
    "//*[re:test(local-name(), '^TEXT.*')]",
    namespaces={'re': "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"})
```

Of course, in the example you mention you don't really need a regular expression. You could use the [`starts-with()`](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string) xpath function:

```
results = root.xpath("//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'TEXT')]")
```

Complete program:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.XML('''
    <root>
      <TEXT1>one</TEXT1>
      <TEXT2>two</TEXT2>
      <TEXT3>three</TEXT3>
      <x-TEXT4>but never four</x-TEXT4>
    </root>''')

result1 = root.xpath(
    "//*[re:test(local-name(), '^TEXT.*')]",
    namespaces={'re': "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"})

result2 = root.xpath("//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'TEXT')]")

assert(result1 == result2)

for result in result1:
    print result.text, result.tag
```

---

Addressing a new requirement, consider this XML:

```
<root>
   <tag>
      <TEXT1>one</TEXT1>
      <TEXT2>two</TEXT2>
      <TEXT3>three</TEXT3>
   </tag>
   <other_tag>
      <TEXT1>do not want to found one</TEXT1>
      <TEXT2>do not want to found two</TEXT2>
      <TEXT3>do not want to found three</TEXT3>
   </other_tag>
</root>
```

If one wants to find all `TEXT` elements that are immediate children of a `<tag>` element:

```
result = root.xpath("//tag/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'TEXT')]")
assert(' '.join(e.text for e in result) == 'one two three')
```

Or, if one wants to all `TEXT` elements that are immediate children of only the first `tag` element:

```
result = root.xpath("//tag[1]/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'TEXT')]")
assert(' '.join(e.text for e in result) == 'one two three')
```

Or, if one wants to find only the first `TEXT` element of each `tag` element:

```
result = root.xpath("//tag/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'TEXT')][1]")
assert(' '.join(e.text for e in result) == 'one')
```

---

Resorources:

- http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/
- http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html

Comment: I used these resources in developing the answer: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/ http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html . You might find them useful, too.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one idea:

```
import lxml.etree

doc = lxml.etree.parse('test.xml')
elements = [x for x in doc.xpath('//*') if x.tag.startswith('TEXT')]
```